# how to provide both node.js & browser support for (sub)modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

Lets' say I've got a sample library split into 2 files: base library and additional module. The base module resides in `module.js`:

```
var Calculator = {
    add: function(a, b) { return a + b; },
    sub: function(a, b) { return a - b; }
};
```

The additional module resides in `submodule.js`:

```
if (typeof Calculator == "undefined") {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        var Calculator = {};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

Calculator.mul = function(a, b) { return a * b; };                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

Calculator.div = function(a, b) { return a / b; };
```

This is how many js libraries are built (main module + submodules), though probably they're configured a lot better. I've prepared a basic `index.html` file:

```
<html>
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="module.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="submodule.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

that loads the library and enables me to execute it inside the browser (console output below):

```
Calculator.add(3,4)
7
Calculator.sub(3,4)
-1
Calculator.mul(3,4)
12
Calculator.div(3,4)
0.75
```

This is all what the library does. Now I want to provide support for node.js (not breaking support for browsers). I've enclosed the definition within immediately-invoked-fun-expr with a root parameter, which is calculated during runtime: node's `module.exports` if it exists or `this==window` otherwise (browser). The code looks like this:

```
(function(root) {

        root.Calculator = {
                add: function(a, b) { return a + b; },
                sub: function(a, b) { return a - b; }
        };

}(typeof module == 'undefined' ? this : module.exports));
```

When I run node, I can import the module:

```
> var c = require('./module.js')
undefined
> c
{ Calculator: { add: [Function], sub: [Function] } }
```

but what can I do to import submodule?

Comment: You might find [the UMD interesting](https://github.com/umdjs/umd).

Comment: @Andy thanks for the link, that's the case. Anyway, I think I still need some advice on how to use that. I think what I need is `nodeAdapter.js` (finally I need node.js and requireJS support)

Answer (score 0):

[socket.io](http://socket.io/) is good example maybe. You can see structure from there.